# When the matter is heated does the photon absorbed by electrons of atoms or by atoms themself?

Tags: thermodynamics

When the matter is heated does the photon absorbs by electrons of atoms or by atoms themself?

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear about what you're asking?

Answer (score 6):

There are 3 ways matter can be heated: [conduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction), [convection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection) and [radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_radiation).  In conduction and convection, heat is transferred by movement of electrons, vibrational energy, and collisions of molecules and atoms, not by photons.

In heat transfer by radiation, photons do carry the energy.  The photon can be absorbed by increasing rotational or vibrational quantized energy levels, not just electronic energy levels.  While it is possible for an electron itself to absorb radiation in the sense of spin states of electrons in a magnetic field, like in [Electron Spin Resonance Spectroscopy](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_paramagnetic_resonance), it is usually not the electron that is absorbing the radiation.

Comment: I think the question is more about the mechanism by which energy is transferred to matter from photons. The answer is good. I'd like to emphasise that this is an electromagnetic process, photons (at IR and visible frequencies) only couple to electron cloud around atoms not the nucleus. So in a nutshell photons are absorbed by electrons. The actual details are material dependent as described in this answer: there are rotational, vibrational and electronic degrees of freedom.

Comment: "*In heat transfer by radiation...*", in thermodynamics terms I think there is no "heat transfer", only "energy transfer" (which can also happen as work, an ordered transfer contrary to heat). In common language and for computational purposes heat is considered a flow for simplification, but it's actually energy which is flowing, as indicated by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_heat_flow): "*Heat is the flow of thermal energy driven by thermal non-equilibrium, so that 'heat flow' is a redundancy*"

Answer (score 0):

Vibration of atoms is the cause of heat normally. But photons carry energy as they are essentially radiation - for example, the heat transfer in stars more massive than our sun,  photons play a massive role in transporting thermal energy.

Convection and conduction transport heat in matter via vibration of atoms - this increases the system's kinetic energy - temperature is a mere measure of that kinetic energy.

This is just to clear some confusion, although I hope I don't add more to your doubt. Humans detect hot objects by nature as our body's wired to detect those higher kinetic energies - temperature is our invention to describe that kinetic energy in that system more abstractly.

Answer (score -2):

The heat is absorbed by the atom (as a whole) by raising it's electrons to higher energy levels.

Comment: Not always, if the heating is not enough to change the chemical properties of the matter, then the energy will be in the movements of the atoms in eachothers potential field upwardly.